# how to passing arg in createStructuredSelector reselect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arguments, react-props, reselect

I am using createStructuredSelector from reselect like:

[image]

I am having a problem passing arguments to selectors. I am able to do event:

`totalScore()`

, which could return something. However, I am unable to get the version with arguments, conceptually event:

```
studentId => total : totalScore(studentId)
```

working.

Can you guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the following method can be used to send our argument to createStructuredSelector.

[image]